# MCC/international calling prefixes list?

Tags: android, mobile

I need to obtain the mobile international dialing prefix code from the MCC number, but I couldn't find a table or a list that relate both things (and country name), maybe I don't naming it correctly... "international dialing prefix code" I mean the number you have to dial when making a call to another country (1 for USA, 44 for UK, 34 for spain, and so on)...

Thank you!

Comment: Could you clarify what, exactly, you want? I'm not sure if you want this in code, just a list of them, or what.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the latest official list of ITU-T Recommendation E.164 assigned country codes at
http://www.itu.int/pub/T-SP-E.164D-11-2011